# What is causing this ERROR: Error 1452 while trying to forward engineer

Tags: sql, forward-engineer

Trying to forward engineer my db and I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cat10e`.`album`, CONSTRAINT `fk_album_artist` FOREIGN KEY (`art_id`) REFERENCES `artist` (`art_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

INSERT INTO `cat10e`.`album` (`album_id`, `art_id`, `label_id`, `album_name`, `album_cost`, `album_tracks`, `album_rating`, `album_producer`, `album_genre`, `album_note`) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'legends of country', 55.55, 4, 4, 'poor jim', 'country', NULL)

SQL script execution finished: statements: 40 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.

Nothing to fetch
```

You can find the SQL statements here: 
http://pastebin.com/kR4h3xJu

Comment: @juergend How is this a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had not put any data into the referenced table. Adding inserts into the artist table solved the error.